# Thread created by static object deleted before DTor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, std, destructor

I have the following classes in my code.
In other words, There is a static object (singletone) which creates thread in CTor, and when its DTor is called, it has some work to be done in the context of this thread (DTor puts some jobs for the thread).

The problem that i face is that when the DTor of B is called there are no other threads running in the process - seems like this thread is killed by process cleanup before calling the destructor of class B.

Anyone knows why this happens? and how to avoid it?

UPD: The problems occures only when Singleton is created from DLL. All works fine when Singleton is created from the same executable.

I am using VS2017

```
  Singleton.dll (A.h + A.cpp)

A.h --> 

#pragma once
#include <thread>

class __declspec(dllexport) A
{
public:
    static A* instance();
    A();
    ~A();
private:
    bool stopFlag;
    std::thread mThread;
};

A.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std;

    A::A()
    {
        mThread = std::thread([this] { while (stopFlag == false) {  } });
    }
    A::~A()
    {
        stopFlag = true;
        mThread.join();
    }

A* A::instance()
{
    static A self;
    return &self;
}
```

================================================================================
    Executable which uses DLL
    main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"


int main()
{
    auto a = A::instance();
    return 0;
}
```

Updated with the compilable code. Now if you compile the first two files as DLL, and then put breakpoint in A's destructor, you will see that thread with lambda function does not exists....

UPDATE: Found an answer by myslef. In Windows, static object from DLL are unloaded ay very last point when all threads are already cleaned up
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Done, and updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer by myslef. In Windows, static object from DLL are unloaded ay very last point when all threads are already cleaned up https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It seems like you wanted to control the thread shutdown cleanly, did you work out a solution for that?

Comment: unfortunately, no. The issue is that the thread is created from DLL static object. This object is destructed after the process already cleaned up all its threads. I found two clean, but not comfort solutions, and one comfort but dirty solution

Comment: 1) Clean - make a done() functions, the user of lib should call it before the process ends. Kill a thread in done() function.
2) Clean - User may wrap your object in its own object, and user's object should call done() function in its desctructor
3) Dirty - do not care- the process is finishing, just let it kill all the used resources (in my case it will work)